# Import a text file, shuffle the contents, display on screen

Tags: python, import, shuffle

I have a list of team names in a txt file.
I want to open the list, shuffle the names then display the result on the screen. Have tried the code below with little success.

```
def shuffle2():
    with open("teams.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
        lines = random.shuffle(myFile.readline())
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.shuffle()` shuffles a list *in place*.

Read your lines into a list first, then shuffle:

```
def shuffle2():
    with open("teams.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
        lines = list(myFile)
    random.shuffle(lines)
    print(lines)
```

Note that the lines will be printed as *one long list*; if you wanted to print them on separate lines, use the `*args` call syntax to pass the lines as separate aguments to `print()`, and set the separator to the empty string:

```
print(*lines, sep='')
```

As each string in `lines` still will include the line separator (`\n`) this'll simply print all the contents of `lines` to the screen with those line separators ensuring that each entry is written out on their own line.

Comment: Massive thanks! Worked perfectly! And the separate lines idea was a good one too! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to shuffle all of the lines before displaying them on the screen.

```
import random

with open("teams.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
    lines = myFile.readlines()

random.shuffle(lines)

print (lines)
```